# PHP counter working locally not remotely

Tags: php, counter

Just wondering if anyone might know why this php counter works perfectly locally (cross-browser tested) but not once the site has been migrated remotely please?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $counter_name = "counter.txt";

    // Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
    if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
    $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
    fwrite($f,"0");
    fclose($f);
}

    // Read the current value of our counter file
    $f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
    $counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
    fclose($f);

    // Has visitor been counted in this session?
    // If not, increase counter value by one
    if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
    $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
    $counterVal++;
    $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
    fwrite($f, $counterVal);
    fclose($f); 
    }

    echo " $counterVal DONATIONS SO FAR";
?>
```

If someone does know the answer, could you please suggest a fix? I appreciate all help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you have rights to open and read counter.txt on your remote server ?

Comment: is this a proper paste:

"    enter code heresession_start();  "

Comment: Sorry Wach it's fixed

Comment: If none of answers posted solved the problem either post own answer so other can benefit from your mistake or delete the question if it's something trivial

Answer (score 0):

As it is working in local PC but not in remote PC, most likely problem is with your file permission. as you need to both read and write in the file please put appropriate permission for that file

```
chmod 777 counter.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a permission problem, but you can easily figure it out calling [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php). If not a permission error, some other process has a lock on the file, or you have zero available disk space (not likely), or session handling fails for some reason.

You can also try to `chmod($counter_name, 0777);` from the PHP code.